# PHP + LDAP find members of memberOf

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I use **sAMAccountName** to search for a user,
after retrieving the user I get the user **"memberof"** list.
I want to fetch all the member of the **"memberof"** from the user.
is it possible to do it in one search?

Nevo.

OK Here is what I got so far:

```
$ds = ldap_connect('145.20.0.10', 389);
$bind = 1;
$bind = ldap_bind($ds, "aa", "aa");
if( $bind ){
      $dn = "OU=all users,DC=mycustomdc,DC=co,DC=il";
      $search = ldap_search($ds, $dn, "(samaccountname=asd)", ['memberOf', 'company','department']);
      $enr = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
}
```

this give me the **memberof**, of the member,
but I need to get the members of the **memberof**

Comment: Please provide us some code where you stuck at or what you have tried. This make it a lot easier for you to get right answers :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are starting with one user account and you want to:

1. Get all the groups that user is a member of (by getting the value of
   'memberOf')
2. Find the members of each group found in step 1.

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Iterate through all the groups and make a separate call to get the 'member' attribute, which will have the list of members.
2. Construct a query based on 'memberOf' to find all other people who are members of the same groups:

> (&(objectClass=user)(|(memberOf=CN=group1,OU=something,DC=mydomain,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=group2,OU=something,DC=mydomain,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=group3,OU=something,DC=mydomain,DC=com)))

It is possible to get different results based on which method you use.

Method 1 will get you any members of the groups, even if they're on other domains outside the domain or forest (for example, domains with one-way trusts).

With method 2 (searching memberOf) your results will be different if you search using LDAP:// (port 389) or GC:// (port 3268). Using GC:// will not work for global or domain local groups, whereas using LDAP:// will. However, if you use LDAP:// you will only get users from one domain, which might be a problem if you have other domains in your AD forest.

If you only have 1 domain in your organization with no trusts to other domains, then you are better off using LDAP://.

Comment: I found out that I can do something like that

`(&(samaccountname=messagetestuser)(|(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MessageUsers,OU=Groups,DC=super-pharm,DC=co,DC=il)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MessageManager,OU=Groups,DC=super-pharm,DC=co,DC=il)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MessageOffice,OU=Groups,DC=super-pharm,DC=co,DC=il)))`
The only problem is that I can't know afterwards which memberof belong to the one up here ^